# Question regarding totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Quoting from Wikipedia article on Euler's totient function theorem :---

> In general, when reducing a power of $a$ modulo $n$ (where $a$ and $n$ are coprime), one needs to work modulo $φ(n)$ in the exponent of $a$:
>
> if $x ≡ y \pmod{φ(n)}$, then $a^x ≡ a^y \pmod{n}$.

Is this really true generally? And how to prove that the original statement in Euler's theorem is equivalent to that?

Comment: My Questions :-- 1. Does it hold for only (a,n)=1 or even when they aren't​ coprime. 2. How to show that this is equivalent to Euler's theorem a^phi(n)=1 mod (n)?

Answer (score 3):

Euler's theorem states:

For all integers $a$ and $n$ with $GCD(a,n)=1$ we have $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\mod n$.

Hence if we assume $x \geq y$ and $x \equiv y \mod \phi(n)$, there is some integer $k$ that satisfies $x = y + k \phi(n)$. Then we get:
$$
a^x = a^{y + k \phi(n)} = a^y \left[a^\phi(n)\right]^k \equiv a^y [1]^k \equiv a^y \mod n
$$
which proves your version with the condition that $a$ and $n$ are coprime. For the reverse and starting with the theorem:

For all integers $a,n,x,y$ with $GCD(a,n)=1$ and $x \equiv y \mod \phi(n)$ we have $a^x \equiv a^y \mod n$.

We consider the special case that $x = y + \phi(n)$, which gives
$$
a^x = a^{y + \phi(n)} \equiv a^y \mod n
$$
and hence
$$
a^{y+\phi(n)} - a^y = a^y \left(a^{\phi(n)} -1 \right) \equiv 0 \mod n
$$
Since $GCD(a,n)=1$ the factor $a^y$ has no common factor with $n$ and hence $a^{\phi(n)} -1$ must be a multiple of $n$, which gives Euler's theorem in the usual form
$$
a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n
$$
So the two theorems are fully equivalent and generally true under the constraint that $a$ and $n$ have no common divisor.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is false when $a$ and $n$ are not coprime.

Take for instance $a=2$ and $n=4$. Then:

$3 \equiv 1 \bmod \phi(2)$ but $2^3 \equiv 0 \not\equiv 2 = 2^1 \bmod 4$.

On the other hand, if $(x \equiv y \bmod \phi(n) \implies a^x \equiv a^y \bmod n)$, then take $x=\phi(n)$ and $y=0$ to get Euler's theorem if $a\ne0$.